# Criar pasta e upar arquivo durante o mesmo insert

Tags: php, pdo

Desejo inserir uma notícia juntamente com o arquivo da imagem num só post, o problema é que gostaria de criar uma pasta com o ID da notícia onde será armazenada a imagem. Está acontecendo que o insert está funcionando mais o upload não, alguma luz ou maneira mais fácil para fazer isso?

```
$imagem = $_FILES['imagem'];

$sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO noticias (titulo,categoria,conteudo) VALUES (:titulo,:categoria,:conteudo)";
$stmt = DB::prepare($sqlInsert);
$stmt->bindParam("titulo", $titulo);
$stmt->bindParam("categoria", $categoria);
$stmt->bindParam("conteudo", $conteudo);
$stmt->execute();

$ultimoid = DB::lastInsertId();
$dir = "../imagens/$ultimoid";
$pasta = mkdir("$dir", 0775);
if(is_dir("$dir")){
  if($arquivo != "none") {
    if (copy($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'], $dir . $_FILES['imagem']['name'])) {
    $arquivo1 = $_FILES['imagem']['name'];
    $sqlInsert = "UPDATE noticias SET imagem=:imagem WHERE idnoticia=$ultimoid";
    }
}
```

lembrando que fiz um resumo do código só com as partes que creio eu é onde está dando problema, qualquer dúvida posto o código inteiro

Comment: Na linha que tem copy, não precisa usar algo do tipo "joinPaths" ? o path está certinho ?

Comment: na teoria se o diretorio foi criado o path esta certo

Answer (score 2):

Você colocou no HTML do  o atributo: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, ele é necessário para fazer o upload via POST.

Confere aqui um exemplo:

```
<form method="post" action="salvar-alguma-coisa.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="arquivo">
    <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvy2tLgo/1/)

Comment: ta tudo cetinho o maior problema mesmo é criar a pasta com o mesmo ID da noticia